# Not able to quit emulator from command line using adb command after upgrading adb tools

Tags: android, adb, emulation, kill

Following command used to work to quit emulator with Android SDK tools version 24.4.1. After updating tools versions to 25.1.6 it stopped working on Mac.

**adb -s emulator-5554 emu kill**

Even following command not working. No error showing in command prompt. 
**adb kill-server**

Looks like newer version having some problems. Does any one know what the reason is? I would like to control emulators programmatically by starting and stopping emulators. All of a sudden stopped working after updating Android SDK tools :-(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and believe the reason is an authentication step for emulator commandline commands that Google introduced in the update to 25.1.6.

A workaround is to kill the emulator through a telnet session that includes this authentication. A nice automated expect script for this telnet session can be found under https://gist.github.com/vaughandroid/310c6d1d12f5473ea2e098982c77443f.

The relevant steps of the expect script are:

```
spawn telnet localhost 5554
expect "OK"
send "auth $TOKEN\r"
expect "OK"
send "kill\r"
expect "OK"
```